# Deriving the fluctuation-dissipation theorem

Tags: statistical-mechanics, non-equilibrium, fluctuation-dissipation

In the derivation of the classical version of the fluctuation-dissipation theorem [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluctuation-dissipation_theorem#Classical_version), they expand the equilibrium distribution function (with Hamiltonian $H(x) = H_{0}(x) - f_{0}x$)

$$ W(x, 0) = \frac{\exp(-\beta H(x))}{\int \exp(-\beta H(x')) \mathrm{d}x'} $$

as

$$ W(x, 0) \approx W_{0}(x)[1 + \beta f_{0}(x(0) - \left<x \right>_{0}]$$

I am assuming they expand $\exp(\beta f_{0}x)$ as $1 + \beta f_{0}x$ but that doesn't really lead me anywhere I believe. Could someone walk me through it?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: It is not clear where you stumble - do you have trouble moving on to the next equation in the cited derivation?

Comment: @Roger Vadim, I have trouble going from the above distribution to the above expansion of $W(x, 0)$. Not the rest of the derivation. What is being expanded and how? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is linear expansion in $f_0$, whereas $W_0(x)\propto \exp(-\beta H_0(x))$. Note also that the stationary distribution does not evolve - that is important when convolving it with $P(x,t|x',t')$.

Comment: @RogerVadim, I am still not sure how to proceed, do you mind helping me out with the last steps? I have:
$$ W(x, 0) = \frac{\exp(-\beta (H_{0}(x) - f_{0}x))}{\int \exp(-\beta (H_{0}(x') - f_{0}x') \mathrm{d}x'} \approx \frac{\exp(-\beta (H_{0}(x))(1 + \beta f_{0}x)}{ \int \exp(-\beta (H_{0}(x') - f_{0}x') \mathrm{d}x'} \approx \frac{W_{0}(x)(1 + \beta f_{0}x)}{ \int \exp(-\beta (H_{0}(x') - f_{0}x') \mathrm{d}x'} $$

How do I get to $ W(x, 0) \approx W_{0}(x)[1 + \beta f_{0}(x(0) - \left<x \right>_{0}]$? 
Thanks for your patience and understanding!

Comment: You have expanded in $f_0$ only the numerator but not the denominator. You need to expand the whole expression to the first order in $f_0$, and the denominator also contributes.

Comment: @RogerVadim, sure but I still can't simplify it:

$$ W(x, 0) \approx \frac{W_{0}(x)(1 + \beta f_{0}x)}{\int \exp(-\beta H_{0}(x')) (1 + \beta f_{0} x') \mathrm{d}x'} = \frac{W_{0}(x)(1 + \beta f_{0}x)}{\int \exp(-\beta H_{0}(x'))\mathrm{d}x'  + \beta f_{0} \int \exp(-\beta H_{0}(x')) x' \mathrm{d}x' }$$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $\left(\frac{u}{v}\right)'=\frac{u'v-uv'}{v^2}$ you are expanding separately the denominator and the numerator, but not the function as a whole.

Comment: @RogerVadim, I see. Is there any chance I can ask you to go through it for me as an answer to the original question? Because I really don't see how to proceed from what you are suggesting. I do understand if you don't have time for that and in that case I want to thank you for the time you already spent.